# How to assign multiple dedicated IP addresses and domains to the same directive in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, virtualdirectories

I am setting up a Magento Multi-Site/Multi-Store structure and the way it works is it sets an environmental variable depending on which domain it is on (distinguishes store); so basically all the domains are pointed to the same directory. The trouble is I need each site domain to use a different IP address for other purposes. I will also needs to install SSL for each store. Does anyone know if this is possible and how I would go about doing this?

If it is any helps the server is Apache 2.2 and its a WHM/cPanel setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/).  It can be used to give each IP/port a seperate site, including SSL certificate, WWWRoot, etc.


--Christopher Karel